# How do I transfer brave bookmarks, settings and passwords from one windows computer to another

Tags: transfer, brave

I have just bought a new laptop.
Both laptops run Windows 10.

How can I transfer bookmarks, settings and save passwords for **brave** to the new laptop.

Comment: Copy the Brave user profile, if it’s not Default, you will have to create a profile with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set up [sync](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021218111-How-do-I-set-up-Sync-) between both devices:

1. On old laptop, click hamburger menu icon [image: Hamburger menu] in top right, then choose `Sync`.
2. Click on `Start a new sync chain` -> choose `Computer` -> copy the code and save it so that it's transferrable.
   [image: Sync setup]
3. On new laptop, once again go to `Sync` menu. Choose `I have a Sync Code` this time. Copy the code and confirm.
4. Wait until it finishes and choose what you want to sync. After everything gets copied, you can remove the sync with old laptop if needed.